# QGIS Buffer tool and Shape Tools circle size does not match

Tags: symbology, buffer, circle

I am trying to create a circle polygon around a point so that I can count population from a raster grid inside that circle. I know this has been well-covered in other posts, and I've managed to do it, but now I have a new problem that I can't find the answer to anywhere.

I have tried to make a circle around a point in 3 different ways, and each time, although I input the distance in metric units, the circle sizes are all different! Infuriating!

Here are the three methods I attempted:
(I am trying to get a circle with a radius of 6.6 km.

1. Visualize a circle as Symbology:
   I used a Simple Marker of Size 13200.0 in units of Meters at Scale, as shown in the picture.
   [image: I used a Simple Marker of Size 13200.0 in units of Meters at Scale, as shown in the picture.]
2. Add circular polygon using Buffer tool:

- First, I reprojected the data point from EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 to EPSG:32735 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_cqIo6IpjQ&t=114s
- Then, I applied a buffer to the reprojected point with a distance of 6600 meters, as shown in the picture.
  [image]

3. Add a circular polygon using Shape Tools --> Create Ellipse

- semi-major and semi-minor axis set equal to 6600 meters, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Finally, the result I get looks like as shown below.
The size order of the circles from smallest to largest: Buffer --> Symbology --> Create Ellipse

Buffer: Golden-Brown

Symbology: Bright Yellow Ring

Create Ellipse: Dark Orange

[image]

????
Could someone please explain what all these different units of "meters" mean?

Comment: In your 1st Screenshot you have a Radius of 13200 instead of 6600. As well, you have several Symbol layers, you should delete all bist the one you need. Advice: create an new point layer in the CRS you use and see if it behaves the same with one Test point. To solve your Problem: can you shared your data+Project?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It is my understanding that the Symbology size goes by diameter, not radius. Is this wrong? In addition, I did already create a duplicate point with just 1 circle. For this project, I need to display circles at multiple distances around the same point. How can I share my data+Project? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you might be right, sorry. Or ist that part of the problem? Ist the site maybe the size of the diagonal of the rectangle (bounding box) of the Symbol?

Comment: Load data to a Cloud and share links here

Comment: I had the same issue trying to create a 5km radius circle. My map is in EPSG:6871. I double checked the distance using the geodesic measure tool and got the following distances:
Buffer tool: 3.45 km
Shape tool (Create circle): 5 km
I double checked the distances using Google Earth Pro and can confirm that in my case the Buffer tool shape was wrong. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVBXM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVBXM.png)